# RTCPeerConnections (or mediaStreams?) hogging memory and CPU even after closed

Tags: javascript, webrtc, cpu, peerjs

I'm currently building a video call app using PeerJS (WebRTC wrapper). In debugging, I noticed that not only did running multiple peer connections use a ton of CPU, but that the CPU usage did not decrease when connections were closed and their respective mediaStreams were stopped.

When a peer disconnects (closes/refreshes the tab) and has a call open, that connection is closed with the peer on the other end. Furthermore, on the "close" event, the other peer stops the terminated peers' stream tracks and removes the video container they were playing in from the DOM with jQuery `remove()`.

```
conn.on("close", () => {
    console.log("conn closed");
    let streamToKill = document.getElementById(`${peerID}`).srcObject;
    streamToKill.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    $(`#${peerID}`).parent().parent().remove();
```

I observed my task manager when running the site. When a peer creates a room and streams their video/mic, about 10% of CPU is used. When another peer calls them and sends their stream, CPU jumps to around 80%.

When the second peer disconnects/closes the connection, I would expect the original peer's CPU usage to drop back down since the stream, video element, and connection are gone, but it remains spiked around 80% and the memory usage of the tab slowly creeps up. Is this an issue with my hardware, code, unloading/disposal of the connection/stream?

Comment: Check chrome://webrtc-internals (switch chrome to your browser). This should load the internals and let you know if things closed correctly. I'd try running a new Peerconnection and with a timeout of 5 seconds close it and see what happens in internals.

Comment: @blanknamefornow The way I have it set up, one peer calls the other to establsh a MediaConnection, and the receiving peer establishes a DataConnection in return. I see the logs for both of these in webrtc-internals. When I kill the first peer, the DataConnection logs a "close" and "connectionStateChange: closed", which is good. The MediaConnection logs "connectionStatechange: disconnected" and "iceConnectionStateChange: disconnected". 15 seconds later, it goes on to log "connectedStateChange: failed" and 11 "iceCandidateErrors"--could this be a culprit, or is this expected?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in my response to @blanknamefornow above, the DataConnection seemed to be closing just fine. I suspected that the `connectionStateChange: failed` and `iceCandidateError`s were caused by the MediaConnection lingering and trying to reconnect, likely still broadcasting the user's mediaStream.

I keep an array to log all open media connections. Thus, to fix the problem, I filtered through the array and closed/removed the MediaConnection with the same peerID as the closed DataConnection.

```
for (var x = 0; x < openMediaConnections.length; x++) {
    let openMediaConn = openMediaConnections[x];
    if (openMediaConn.peer == peerID) {
        openMediaConn.close();
        openMediaConnections.splice(x, 1)
    }
};
```

Now, the CPU decreases to around 25% when the call is disconnected, which is a great improvement. Thank you to blanknamefornow!

Comment: Glad you were able to sort it, not always is it easy to diagnose the issues. Luckily we have our internals to monitor the flow and incoming/outgoing packets. Oddly I will add that some browsers behave weirdly with ice-candidate, chrome for instance I've noticed on many app sites will trickle but then error out but the transport was made still. Odd but this is relatively new stuff and from what I read every browser handles different so do trial around different browsers to see if you exhibit similar behaviors if you need to further debug.